# ConvergenceWarning: Maximum Likelihood slows kernel-run-time?

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, statsmodels

I use the very nicht code-object `arma_order_select_ic` in order to finde the lowest Information Criterion for chor choosing p- and q values.

I am not sure if i do it right or if the code just stumbles upon some mistakes...

In:

```
y = indexed_df
res = arma_order_select_ic(y, max_ar=7, max_ma=7, ic=['aic', 'bic', 'hqic'], trend='c', fit_kw=dict(method='css'))
print res
print ('AIC-order: {}' .format(res.aic_min_order))
print ('BIC-order: {}' .format(res.bic_min_order))
print ('HQIC-order: {}' .format(res.hqic_min_order))
```

Out:

```
/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels-0.6.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/statsmodels/base/model.py:466: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to converge. Check mle_retvals
  "Check mle_retvals", ConvergenceWarning)
```

Plus: it prints out the three matrix-style lists (for each IC one matrix) with the final recommendation:

```
AIC-order: (7, 5)
BIC-order: (7, 0)
HQIC-order: (7, 0)
```

So, the whole thing seems to work.

The problem is, it takes approx 30-60 seconds as the warning is printed for every calculation i.e. it is super slow!

I checked the relevant source code (statsmodels/base/model.py) and how to skip printing the CovergenceWarning:

```
   #TODO: hardcode scale?
        if isinstance(retvals, dict):
            mlefit.mle_retvals = retvals
            if warn_convergence and not retvals['converged']:
                from warnings import warn
                from statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions import ConvergenceWarning
                warn("Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to converge. "
                     "Check mle_retvals", ConvergenceWarning)

        mlefit.mle_settings = optim_settings
        return mlefit
```

So i tried to delete the if part which is linked to the ConvergenceWarning but it wont work.

This part from the same source code:

```
mle_retvals : dict
    Contains the values returned from the chosen optimization method if
    full_output is True during the fit.  Available only if the model
    is fit by maximum likelihood.  See notes below for the output from
    the different methods.
```

does not tell me where and how to change mle_retvals

How to check the mle_retvals and what to change?

Is there a way to make the ConvergenceWarning disappear to make the calculation run faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation in the Notes section explicitly states how you can speed things up...See the docstring for `fit_kw` to change arguments given to the `ARMA.fit` method. This is going to be slow for high numbers of models. It's a naive implementation and just does a pairwise fit of them all. Try doing `method='css'` for faster results.

I don't know why you want to change `mle_retvals`. It is in the returns section. It's not something you change directly. You shouldn't have to delete any source code to get things to run. That check is there to warn you that things are going wrong. I.e., it might be the case that the models causing these warnings are really poor models for your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and hide the warnings.

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=ConvergenceWarning)
    y = indexed_df
    res = arma_order_select_ic(y, max_ar=7, max_ma=7, ic=['aic', 'bic', 'hqic'], trend='c', fit_kw=dict(method='css'))
    print res
    print ('AIC-order: {}' .format(res.aic_min_order))
    print ('BIC-order: {}' .format(res.bic_min_order))
    print ('HQIC-order: {}' .format(res.hqic_min_order))
```